# Reference: Varadhan's lemma for Finsler Geometry?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation, large-deviations

Is there a version of Varadhan's lemma for heat-kernels on Finsler manifolds?  I expect this to exist but I cannot seem to find any papers on the topic.  References would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the heat equation for a Finsler metric is nonlinear, so there is no heat kernel per se.

Comment: If I assume the finsler function is L^p norm on the tangent spaces.would that help?

Comment: Perhaps you should first make precise what you mean by a heat kernel.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: My comment was about any definition of the heat kernel that I could imagine. But it occurs to me that you might have a specific definition in mind that I don't know about. So I was asking for clarification on this.

Comment: Could you give me a referene to the heat equation on Finsler manifolds?

Comment: You can find several papers if you google "heat flow Finsler". if you want to define the heat flow in terms of a "Finsler Laplacian", which in turn is defined using an energy functional analogous to the $L^2$ norma of the gradient, then everything is nonlinear. Even for the $L^p$ norm. You can do the calculations yourself.

Comment: You can also google "p-Laplacian heat flow"